# Fiware get access token seems to get wrong

Tags: fiware-orion

We are having troubles with getting the access token from fiware since 4th August. 
We are using this URL to ask for the token: https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token but it seems like it does not work.

Before using that URL we used to ask for this one: 
http://cloud.lab.fi-ware.org:4730/v2.0/tokens

Could anyone, please, help us?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to get the token. The current OAuth2 URL to get the tokens is https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token. This is the central authority for authentication, if you are accessing any common GE, but you will need to register your application in FIWARE Account and use your application credentials and some OAuth2 grant to get it.

If you want to get the token for the global instance without using a registered application, the URL you have mentioned contains a token service that can give you a valid token for your user and that purpose. You can test it (and see an example) with the following script:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh

Comment: Thank you Daniel.

We don't have a registered app, we access to the goblal instance. We are using the URL that I mentioned, https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token, since 1st July, but as I told you the last 4th August it seemed to be broken. I've just checked out our log files, and it seems like it's working fine again, since 8:55 this morning. Maybe someone has fixed it.

Thanks again.